# BIOSTAR B350GT5 ram support 2666mhz

Tags: amd-ryzen

I recently bought a new pc and i'm not sure if 2666mhz works with my motherboard (biostar b350gt5)

Specs:
CPU - Ryzen 3 2200G
RAM - Ripjaws V  8GB (2x4GB) 2666mhz
PSU - XGR 600W
HDD - 1TB (nothing on)

Right now the PC turns on but the screen displays nothing so im wondering if its because of the ram...

Comment: Try one RAM stick at a time. You may probably need to upgrade BIOS on your board before it can detect Ryzen-G CPU.

Comment: I tried with one stick of ram (still didn't work) and i cant update the bios because the screen wont show anything (pc wont boot so im guessing there is something wrong with POST.. but im thinking its the ram cause everything else is working fine)

Comment: One simple check you can do is hook a motherboard speaker to 4 pin speaker header on the board. Remove all RAM, disconnect HDD and power on. If CPU is active you shall hear a few beeps indicating missing RAM as BIOS does power on self test. You may have to take help of computer vendor or Biostar service center to update BIOS in your case. Lower version of BIOS is one of the possibilities as B350 boards came out before Raven Ridge APUs (AMD Ryzen-G) and they support them only after certain BIOS revisions.

Comment: Do check if there's any sticker on board that indicates BIOS rev it was shipped with and crosscheck with vendor site if that rev is good enough to detect Ryzen-G APUs. Other things to check for are all connections, monitor cables etc are firmly plugged in, in the right socket. Also make sure that there’s no accidental short between board and the cabinet metallic part anywhere.